# Design pattern to create a shared lib architecture

Tags: design-patterns, c++, c, libraries, dynamic-linking

I am making a renderer as a hobby, one thing I thought to try is making the low levelAPI be dynamically swappable, i.e. you could have an opengl or vulkan backend and switch between the two without needing to recompile or even relaunch the application.

To achieve this I am making 2 binaries, one is the executable, the other is the rendering code.

Let's call them `main` and `rendering`. For this to work, there is a core header `Core.hpp` that defines all the C like functions and message PODs that are used to pass information between `main` and `rendering`.

I have one issue, I need to create objects/class instances in `rendering`. Due to a series of constraints these are C++ instead of C, which means they cannot easily pass the barrier between the 2 binaries.

Because these objects need to live for as long as the rendering code is available, my current approach to handling their memory is to allocate on the heap into global pointers that are deleted when the `main` calls a deinit method. For example, the memory allocation object would be initialized like this

```
MemoryAllocHandler * mem_handler;

void Init()
{
   mem_handler = new MemoryAllocHandler();
}

void deinit()
{
    delete mem_handler;
}
```

This way I can expose a C like API that receives parameters and uses these objects to handle rendering (fro example allocating OpenGL buffers).

This works, but I hate it. If I was statically linking rather than dynamic linking, I would not allocate on the heap, I would allocate on the stack and return these objects, hold them in some structure initialized at the highest possible scope and rely on RAII idioms to have its memory freed.

For example:

```
MemoryAllocHandler Init()
{
   return MemoryAllocHandler();
}
```

Is there a way I could do something like the above while still dynamically linking? Take into account the prior is A C++ function with a C++ struct return type so name mangling is not just present but necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it's impossible to allocate things on the stack without knowing their size at compile-time - which is what you want. At least, it isn't possible in C or C++ in a convenient way. You can use `alloca` but it's really ugly.

But you can still get RAII with heap-allocated objects. Just use `std::unique_ptr`:

```
// in DLL
std::unique_ptr<BaseMemoryAllocHandler> Init()
{
   return std::make_unique<VulkanMemoryAllocHandler>();
   // VulkanMemoryAllocHandler derives from BaseMemoryAllocHandler
   // Make sure BaseMemoryAllocHandler has a virtual destructor
}

// in executable
int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<BaseMemoryAllocHandler> mem_handler = Init();
    std::cout << "hello world\n";
    // mem_handler is automatically deleted at this point
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seen as this is a C++ library, why not use a third common library that encapsulates the abstractions which the two other libraries implement, and also contains the long lived common objects?

This side steps the issues of name mangling (assuming common versioning), and makes it so that long lived objects are handle by the one library that is not swapped out.

A naive C wrapper around this is relatively trivial.

Comment: because the rendering library is a plugin to the core library. The idea is someone else could come along and do their own implementation, then just implement a common interface.

The long lived common objects are likely different from implementation to implementation.

Comment: Ah, I think I worded that poorly. The common library would hold common abstractions that implementors can extend for their specific output api. It would also hold common data structures the the client would use to communicate with these implementations, such as an image buffer to relay 2d images, or a mesh structure to relay meshes. As the client does not know which api is being used it cannot pre-emptively pass in optimised data, but pass in generic data that the implementation either directly renders from, or translates to an optimal form.

Comment: This would fit your example very well, as for example the vulcan API can store whatever details its needs to within a `Frame` object (or whatever you call the rendering window). The client would then clean this up naturally as a consequence of deconstructing the object.

Answer (score 0):

How would I do that:

Rendering DLL (`rendering`) can be written in C++ but must have a C API like that:

```
// rendeing.h

VERTEX_BUFFER* CreateVertexBuffer(size_t size);
void           DeleteVertexBuffer(VERTEX_BUFFER*);
```

On the client side (`main`) if you wish you can wrap it into some C++ API like that (RAII):

```
class VertexBuffer
{
public:
    explicit VertexBuffer(size_t size)
    {
        buf = CreateVertexBuffer(size);
    }

    ~VertexBuffer()
    {
        DeleteVertexBuffer(buf);
    }

    // here go C++ complexities to disable copying and stuff like that.
}
```

Comment: The issue here is that there are objects in the rendering DLL that must be stored somewhere, for example vulkan needs an instance object, which needs to be kept around. You either keep it around in teh DLL ore the library that consumes, ideally I am trying to have it be stored int eh consumer.

Comment: I am not familiar with Vulkan API but I guess Vulkan instance is something like OpenGL context or Direct3D Device object. You need an abstraction in your rendering library for that and some API like Rendering_CreateDevice(), Rendering_DestroyDevice()

Comment: I's similar except usually the OGL context is kept around for you, whereas an isntance is an object that must be initialized and deleted manually

Comment: OGL context is an object too which may require manual creation/destruction (look at eglCreateContext, eglDestroyContext) its a platform code which usually hides this complexity when you work with OGL.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. You could force the RAII structure by making a "shadow main" function that takes a callback. Even a C-style "pointer to function taking no arguments and returning void" callback.

Then your shadow main function can create the objects and call the callback. The library consumer runs their entire program in the callback. On normal exit, they return and unwind through your RAII code.

The downside of this is that it forces a particular structure on programs that consume this library. It makes it very difficult to use inside another library as well, unless that library also uses this pattern.